# Create an enum based on another enum in swift 2

Tags: swift, enums

Consider a case that you want to create a master enum which contains all possible outcomes of a generic operation (like a server response to different requests which have both generic and specialized outcomes). And then you want to categorize possible outcomes for different operations, but you want to use the master enum to avoid redefining cases over and over again. how could it be possible? You can't possibly inherit enums in swift, so there goes the inheritance and you can't assign values from other enums as values for your enum cases.

An example of a use case:

```
 // Here is the master enum which contains all possible conditions

 enum ServerError: ErrorType{

    case Forbidden(String?)
    case Malformed(String?)
    case NotFound(String?)
    case InternalError(String?)
    case Unauthorized(String?)
    ...
}
```

The following doesn't work because swift complains that

> Raw type "ServerError.ServerError" is not convertible to any literal

```
   enum LoginError : ServerError {

    case ServerError.NotFound(String?)
    case ServerError.InternalError(String)

}
```

I'm not trying to do exactly this, I'm just looking for a way to accomplish the idea: Subsetting a master enum in different enums so that they can be reused and safely switch-cased on only possible cases for a situation.

Let me know if my question needs any further clarifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called **inheritance**, and you cannot inherit between enums or structs.

So you best bet is to you use **class** where you will have one class called `ServerError` and the one called `LoginError`

Comment: How that helps with switch casing?! You can't switch on different properties of a class. I'm sure we can find a way.

Comment: your switch cased are based from the user's input right?

Comment: Well not exactly, it's based on server's response in this case. The idea is that in every operation's response handler, I will have a possible error form server, I need to switch case on possible errors only. You see, I can handle all master enums cases in all operations but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: Therefore you have to create function that holds or returns all the responses inside of that ServerError class. however inheriting between both enums will not be possible because its not allowed

Comment: That's what i'm doing right now, My master enum has an initializer which takes operation's type and server's response and generates a possible `ServerError` but, where I should handle the generated error, I'm facing all possible outcomes, regardless of the operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98765/discussion-between-m-porooshani-and-lamar).